# Taking time off after giving two-week notice?

Tags: interviewing, quitting, notice-period

I recently submitted my two-week notice and was interviewing with another company. I was made an offer and a start date. They want me to come in and do paperwork, meet colleagues, managers, etc..(lasting two hours). I've given my notice and I'm not sure whether to take a sick day or use my vacation days I have left.

Company policy states no vacations after two-week notice but nothing about sick days. Will this look bad if I take a sick day?

Comment: I did, once I received the offer, I submitted my two-weeks. I was contacted by the new company a week later and they wanted me to meet with their team and tour the facilities.

Comment: If it's only a couple of hours could you work something out with your current employer to make up the hours?

Comment: Have you determined what you need to do during this notice period? I've had jobs where they want all the time they can get and others that have a policy that you leave immediately and they'll pay you for two weeks.

Comment: I will speak with HR and see if I can leave earlier than the two week period. I know some others who quit were given an option to leave earlier. Our department is very short-staffed also which doesn't help my case......

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this will look bad.

Doing paperwork, touring the facilities, and meeting new colleagues all sound like normal tasks for the first day of a new job. Why don't you ask your new company if you can do it then?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will look bad - but unless your company has some policy or way of determining if you really were sick - what can they do?

This isn't 'bridge-burning' behavior, and you don't need a reference from them anyway, since you already have a new job.

Technically you are stealing a day of pay (assuming you have paid sick leave) though...

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure whether to take a sick day or use my vacation days I have left.

> Company policy states no vacations after two-week notice

Well straight away let's rule that out: you cannot use your vacation days (of course, you *could* still ask, but that's unlikely to be a possibility).

I don't think a company can really forbid you from using your sick days, and people do get sick in their last two weeks, just as they get sick on their first day of the job, as unfortunate as it is. You could definitely use a sick day. It will look bad, but it won't be the end of the world and I don't imagine it would be held against you for longer than your remaining time at the company. Sure, everyone will gossip on the day, but that's probably as bad as it gets.

---

> I was made an offer and a start date. They want me to come in and do paperwork, meet colleagues, managers, etc..(lasting two hours)

As [Rachael states in their answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/96487/39976), this kind of admin stuff should really be done on the first day. I can't imagine any business that would expect you to be productive on day one.

You should contact your new employer in the same manner you have been (e-mail, phone, whatever) and simply explain that the start date you agreed to was the absolute earliest you could start, and you haven't taken a vacation week (something people sometimes do) between jobs. I'd imagine once you contact them, they should be flexible in allowing you to do this on the first day, and I don't see this being held against you.

Ultimately, would you rather (potentially) upset your new employer by stating you won't come in till your start date, or (potentially) upset your old employer with a sick day? I don't think either situation will be the worse to find yourself in, and likely after a week it'll be water under the bridge.